# Сделать выборку из базы данных по месяцу и дате в диапозоне

Tags: php, mysql

Как сделать выборку из базы данных в диапозоне даты и месяца
например показать все строки таблицы где дни рождения с 21 января по 14 февраля
в php. Вообще это возможно? dr_date  имеет тип данных date в базе данных

```
<?php
$dr_strart = 21.01;
$dr_finish = 14.02;

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE dr_date >= $dr_strart AND  dr_date <= $dr_finish  ");

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [функции для работы с датой](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Date_and_time_functions.html), в данном случае `DATE_FORMAT()`:

```
$dr_strart = '01.21';
$dr_finish = '02.14';

SELECT * FROM users
 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(dr_date,'%m.%d') between $dr_strart AND $dr_finish
```

Только формат даты используйте именно месяц-день, что бы сравнение корректно работало.

Comment: Работает спасибо, а как сделать по возрастания вроде того, как  ORDER BY

Comment: @ВикторВасильев Именно так как вы и подумали, `ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(dr_date,'%m.%d')`